# How do I navigate in the results of Diff

Tags: git

When I do a Git diff, it shows the code with the diff and it looks great. But how do I go to the next page or the next document.

Comment: d takes you down. u takes you up

Answer (score 212, accepted):

```
Next line             : return
Next page             : space bar
Previous page         : w
Quit viewing the diff : q
Help                  : h
```

Comment: Nice, is there a man page on this? i.e. does it use `less`/`more` style keys?

Comment: Alternatively, `f` and `b` navigate pages *f*orward and *b*ackward.

Comment: In a nice meta way, these commands work for navigating the help page as well 

Answer (score 11):

Hit `?` and it should show you the command shortcuts for doing page up/page down etc.

By default `git` looks at the `$GIT_PAGER`, then `$PAGER` environment variable to determine the program to be used for showing you the output of diff, log, show etc.

On new (linux) systems the default `$PAGER` used (even when it is not set) is `less` (it used to be the less capable `more`).

In both `less` and `more` the `?` key gives you a command shortcut list.

Comment: It also looks at the `core.pager` config variable. And generally, none of those three are usually set, and Git defaults to `less -FRSX` (note that it's Git making that choice).

Answer (score 4):

**For scrolling  downwards
 Use**
j or ↓ to move down one line at a time
d to move by half the page screen
f to move by a whole page screen

**For scrolling upwards use**
k or ↑ to move up one line at a time
u to move by half the page screen
b to move by a whole page screen

press **q** to quit out of the log 
It will returns to the regular command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider installing [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/) (Mac) or [gitg](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg) (Ubuntu) for wonderful (and easy) gui options :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running what I think is a stock git install on Windows, msysgit 1.8.3, and for me git diff runs something that claims to be less, version 444.
Instead of '?' for help, it wants 'h'.
Seems that '?' is the start of some kind of regular expression search.